# react native trustkit dependency: could not find com.datatheorem.truskit:trustkit-android

Tags: react-native, trustkit

I'm following this guide to setup trustkit SSL pinngin:
https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit-Android

I'm getting an error trying to install the trust kit dependency

my build.gradle looks like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.datatheorem.truskit:trustkit-android:1.1.3'

    if (enableHermes) {
      def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";
      debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
      releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
      implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

error:

```
 Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.datatheorem.truskit:trustkit-android:1.1.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/Users/omar/.m2/repository/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.pom
       - file:/Users/omar/.m2/repository/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.jar
       - file:/Users/omar/workspace/js/contextful/node_modules/react-native/android/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.pom
       - file:/Users/omar/workspace/js/contextful/node_modules/react-native/android/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.jar
       - file:/Users/omar/workspace/js/contextful/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.pom
       - file:/Users/omar/workspace/js/contextful/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.jar
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.jar
       - https://maven.google.com/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.jar
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/datatheorem/truskit/trustkit-android/1.1.3/trustkit-android-1.1.3.jar
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Comment: why are you not replying me?

Comment: I'm sorry super busy need 2 days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:**

use implementation like this [Docs](https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit-Android#adding-trustkit-as-a-dependency)

```
implementation 'com.datatheorem.android.trustkit:trustkit:1.1.3'
```

I have **tested**. it is working

-

**Problem:**

**don't use**  below dependency because that is not exist

```
implementation 'com.datatheorem.truskit:trustkit-android:1.1.3'
```